# Carthage nested dependencies

Tags: swift, ios-frameworks, carthage

I am fairly new to iOS frameworks but playing around `Carthage` and `Swift` I came to a very simple question yet I didn't seem to find the answer I am looking for.

I am currently playing around `Alamofire` and `ObjectMapper` libs and found that there is another framework called `AlamofireObjectmaper` which gracefully creates a link between those two.

Now my question is how should I handle this in my Cartfile? My first idea was to include all three

```
github "Alamofire/Alamofire" ~> 3.0
github "Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper" ~> 1.1
github "tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper" ~> 2.1
```

But then I figured that since `AlamofireObjectMapper` relies embeds both `Alamofire` and `ObjectMapper` inside it's own framework, I didn't need to include those two. So I removed everything and only added the single `AlamofireObjectMapper` line. And my prototype is still working well (I can still `import Alamofire` in my code.

How exactly should I handle such situation? Should I keep the single `Alamofire` and `ObjectMapper frameworks. And if so, how are they actually handled by Carthage?

Because from what i've seen, the `AlamofireObjectMapper` framework does contain it's own version of the `Alamofire` framework. Could it happen that both `Alamofire` frameworks contains different version at some point? If so, wouldn't that cause any trouble at run time?

Comment: Seems to me that AlamofireObjectMapper has Alamofire and ObjectMapper as submodules inside the Carthage folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I definitely think you are good to go by simply including the `AlamofireObjectMapper` framework, simply because it appears that it's repo checks in its Carthage resources, including the `Cartfile`. Therefore, when you update `AlamofireObjectMapper`, all of ITS dependencies will be updated accordingly.

If for some reason, however, you feel the need to manually update or downgrade (bad idea) one of `AlamofireObjectMapper` dependencies, you could simply go into its Cartfile and change the version number or version operation from `~>` to `==` or whatever you might need to do. Hope this helps!